How can I add new contact types?
I want to add new contact types for users to select from. Can anyone direct me where I can do that? Thank you!

you can add contact sub types
Civi >> Administer >> Customise Data and Screens >> Contact Types
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/contacts/#contact-subtypes

Perfect, thank you!
